# GRE Ratio Question

Tags: gre-exam

> A pancake recipe calls for 1/5 cup of sugar for every cup of flour.
>
> ### Quantity A
>
> Number of cups of sugar in 2 cups of sugar/flour mix
>
> ### Quantity B
>
> 2/5 cups of sugar

### The following are the answer choices

Select A if it's always greater.

Select B if it's always greater.

Select C if A & B are the same.

Select D if it can't be determined.

I know the answer but the explanation in the book sucks can someone please break down this problem in the most simple form and help me solve it step by step.

Comment: I solved this question as follows.

First we know that given ratio is 1/5 to 1.

so we can add the sugar and flour ratio to to get the total mix.

1 + 1/5 = 6/5.

Then we know that proportion of sugar to mix is 1/5/6/5 = 1/6 for 1 cup.

if we want to know how much sugar for 2 cups we can multiply it by 2 and get 2 * 1/6 = 1/3 which is less then the quantity b. Therefore quantity b will always be greater.

Answer (score 4):

If we add $\frac{1}{5}$ of a cup of sugar to every cup of flour, then to get $\frac{2}{5}$ of a cup of sugar we'd need $2$ cups of flour. Then, the total mixture would be $2\frac{2}{5}$ cups containing $\frac{2}{5}$ of a cup of sugar. If we only took $2$ cups of that, we'd have less than $\frac{2}{5}$ cups of sugar.

Comment: thanks for the tip i added my solution under my question as a comment.